# deriving the parametric position vector of a ball flight

Tags: calculus, integration, ordinary-differential-equations

I am investigating the flight of a golf ball using mathematics, and I'm kind of stuck. For this investigation, im looking at the flight of a golf ball when it is experienceing all 3 forces (gravity, linear drag due to air resistance and the lift caused by the magnus effect).

http://ww2.odu.edu/~agodunov/teaching/phys420/files/Erlichson.pdf

So I'm using this essay as the base of my research, and on page 360, it gives the newton equation for when the ball is experiencing all 3 forces.

[equation](https://i.stack.imgur.com/mOcPh.png)

I'm trying to derive a parametric position equation from this equation but Im stuck because it includes both vertical and horizontal velocities.

I'm planning on using integrating factor, but im not getting anywhere

Could someone help?

Comment: Just curious, are you familiar with methods involving solutions of the matrix ODE $\vec{x}'(t)= A \vec{x}$ and the associated inhomogeneous problem $\vec{x}'(t)= A \vec{x}+\vec{x}_0$. In your case of course replace x with v

Comment: Hello Triatticus. No, this is the first time hearing about inhomogeneous problems and methods to solve the matrix which you mentioned. Is this something way beyond my level or am i forgetting something really important? (Currently, I am pursuing the IB HL math diploma) Thank you for your comment